# how to add the name of item to the dataframe name in a loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have this list that has folders names:

```
scenarios_list=[2020,2021,2022]
```

I would like to create a dataframe that adds the name of the folder as this:

```
for i in scenarios_list:
    typology_+i = pd.read_file(path+"\\"+i+"\\"+'data.csv')
```

so I would have 3 dataframes:
typology_2020
typology_2021
typology_2022

Comment: either store them in a list, or a dict: `typologies = {"2020": pd.read_file(f"{path}\{i}\data.csv"), ...}` for instance

Answer (score 1):

as buran pointed, this worked:

```
for i in scenarios_list:
    globals()['typology_{}'.format(i)] =pd.read_file(path+"\\"+i+"\\"+'data.csv')
```